# Error pushing Rails application to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu, heroku

I'm doing an application in RoR from Linux/Ubuntu and deploying in Heroku but when I try to push to Heroku I get this error:

```
       Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:herokuangelapp.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:herokuangelapp.git'
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try running `rake assets:precompile` on local machine and fix the errors that will come up. This question has been asked a million times before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Precompilation**

Without knowing the *exact* error, the question arises as to what the error itself is saying. The problem you have is Heroku's `precompilation` system won't be able to precompile the assets for your Rails application (obviously)

The causes of this could be numerous, but the main culprit is that you have **syntax errors** in your asset files, preventing them from being precompiled.

--

**Local**

As recommended in the comments, you should precompile the assets locally using the following command:

```
$ rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

This will run the precompilation process on your local machine, and will return any exceptions that occur throughout the process.

In order to get it working, you need to clean up *any* of the syntax errors which are returned with this local precompilation process